# display mean value (rearrange data frame?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to boxplot two groups (A and B) and display the mean value on each box plot.

I have 30 lines and 2 columns : each line contains the value of group A (col 1) and group B (col 2).

I did a boxplot with graphic boxplot
`boxplot(Data_Q4$Group.A,Data_Q4$Group.B,names=c("group A","group B"))`

but it seems like adding a mean point on the boxplot necessiting ggplot 2.

I tried many things but it already send me an error message
`! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (30): x...`
It seems my problem come from y axis. I need him to take the data from columns A and B but I don't know how to do this.
if my data was with value column and group columns (A or B for each line) it would work but I don't know how to rearrange it so that I get 2 columns (value and groups) and 60 lines with the values of the groups.
and then I do `dataQ4 %>% ggplot(aes(x=group,y=value))+geom_boxplot+stat_summary(fun.y=mean)`
I think it will be ok.
so my problem is to rearrange my data frame so that I can use ggplot and boxplot it

[image: this is what I want to do]

[image: to plot this]

thanks for your help !

I share here my data :

`dput(Data_Q4) structure(list(Group.A = c(1.25310535, 0.5546414, 0.301283, 1.29312466,  0.99455579, 0.5141743, 2.0078324, 0.42224244, 2.17877257, 3.21778902,  0.55782935, 0.59461765, 0.97739581, 0.20986658, 0.30944786, 1.10593627,  0.77418776, 0.08967408, 1.10817666, 0.24726425, 1.57198685, 4.83281274,  0.43113213, 2.73038931, 1.13683142, 0.81336825, 0.83700649, 1.7847654,  2.31247163, 2.90988727), Group.B = c(2.94928948, 0.70302878,  0.69016263, 1.25069011, 0.43649776, 0.22462232, 0.39231981, 1.5763435,  0.42792839, 0.19608026, 0.37724368, 0.07071508, 0.03962611, 0.38580831,  2.63928857, 0.78220807, 0.66454197, 0.9568569, 0.02484568, 0.21600677,  0.88031195, 0.13567357, 0.68181725, 0.20116062, 0.4834762, 0.50102846,  0.15668497, 0.71992076, 0.68549794, 0.86150777)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -30L))`

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 0):

First I create some random data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), 15),
                 value = runif(30, 0, 10))
```

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "darkred", position = position_dodge(0.75),
               geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 3,
               show.legend = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

The red dots represent the mean.

## Using your data:

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
dataQ4 %>%
  melt() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "darkred", position = position_dodge(0.75),
               geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 3,
               show.legend = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Clara Simon, I changed my code with your data under the header `using your data`.